# Datagrid height in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I only want the height of my Datagrid to be the height of as many row that are returned.  I don't want the greyspace below the rows.

How Can I resolve this Please?

Thanks

```
       <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="5" Grid.RowSpan="8" IsReadOnly="True" AlternatingRowBackground="SteelBlue" AlternationCount="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,17,0,11" Name="dgEmp" Width="1000"  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Name"  Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=EmpName}"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="UID"  Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=UID}" />
```

Comment: The height of `DataGrid` auto-adjusts by default.  Can you show how you're using it, post your code?

Comment: try to set vertical alignment to top <DataGrid VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code worked for me.

```
    <Grid Name="parent">
        <DataGrid VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=parent,Path=Height}" Name="dg"/>
    </Grid>
```